# Pyspark - identical dataframe filter operation gives different output

Tags: dataframe, hadoop, pyspark

I’m facing a particularly bizarre issue while firing filter queries on a spark dataframe. Here's a screenshot of the filter command I'm trying to run:

[image: Similar code, different output]

As you can see, I'm trying to run the same command multiple times. Each time, it's giving a different number of rows. It is actually meant to return 6 records, but it ends up showing a random number of records every time.
FYI, The underlying data source (from which I'm creating the dataframe) is an Avro file in a Hadoop data lake.

This query only gives me consistent results if I cache the dataframe. But this is not always possible for me because the dataframe might be very huge and hence would choke up memory resources if I cache it.

What might be the possible reasons for this random behavior? Any advice on how to fix it?

Many thanks :)

Comment: have you tried giving `.show()` an argument, like 10 for example to print 10 rows?

Comment: It's not only a problem of show() method, the count() method also returns a different number of rows on a similar kind of operation run multiple times, which is deterministically pointing out to some problems in filter operation.

Comment: Check if the underlying directory is getting updated, also try caching the output and then perform the same operation and see the results. if the number of records are less use show and dump the input and output both into flat file and compare.

Comment: R u using any window functions like row number or lead , lag before the step, if your window function can't uniquely identify records due to duplicates and randomly pick a record then this such issues can happen

Comment: I'm doing 3 steps before I create this dataframe from a source data lake: fillna, dropDuplicates and join. There are no window functions that are being done.